# On Mailgun, The Logs show the error: 4.7.1 Received too many messages from a new or untrusted IP

Tags: mailgun

We send a copy of a form that resides on WordPress in Gravity Forms using Mailgun.  The account connects and shows the email in the log file on Mailgun.
However, the email is not sent out of Mailgun to the recipient.
The log shows this error on the email: 4.7.1 Received too many messages from a new or untrusted IP
The detail text of the message from the log shows:

```
delivery-status": {
        "tls": true,
        "mx-host": "mx1.emailsrvr.com",
        "code": 451,
        "description": "",
        "session-seconds": 0.41779112815856934,
        "retry-seconds": 1800,
        "attempt-no": 3,
        "message": "4.7.1 Received too many messages from a new or untrusted IP: 104.130.122.25 (Z27/3E18C53) (G28)",
        "certificate-verified": true
```

I can find no reference to this on Mailgun or what to do to correct the problem.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: welcome! how many messages are you sending? have you contacted mailgun support?

Comment: I had sent five tests in a row over about an hour. It seems you can't ask their support any question unless you pay for a subscription. At the present, I am testing and do not belive I will have the volume to upgrade beyond the free account stage for a while.